# Add comments to Webform submissions

Tags: 8, webforms, comments

I'm trying to figure out allow commenting on the submissions so there can be a back and forth dialog between the user and site admin(s).

In Drupal 8 webform submissions are entities (type: webform_submission) and comments are a field.

I have created a new Comment Type (webform_submission_comment) with the "Target entity type" set to webform_submission).

How do I attach a comment field to the webform_submission entity?

Answer (score 3):

Webform submissions are content entities without Field API  enabled.  Comments can only be attached to fieldable entities.  Webform submission data is not stored Field API, but your use case is a very reasonable example of why Field API could/should be enabled.  The challenge is the UX for supporting fields, and webform elements at the same time could be overwhelming.  I am not prepared to support this the core Webform module.  A dedicated webform_comment.module could be created to enable Field API and might even only support for adding comments to submissions.

---

You are going to have use [hook_entity_type_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_alter/8.2.x) to add 'field_ui_base_route' to the WebformSubmission entity.

> If your content entity is fieldable, provide 'field_ui_base_route' 
>   annotation, giving the name of the route that the Manage Fields,
>   Manage Display, and Manage Form Display pages from the Field UI
>   module will be attached to. This is usually the bundle settings edit
>   page, or an entity type settings page if there are no bundles.

-- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/8.2.x

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Can you offer a place to start in making the Webform submission entity fieldable?

Comment: I added some more notes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working rather easily by doing the following:

1. Implement the following hook in my custom module and clear the cache:

/**

- Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
- 
- @param array $entity_types
- @return void
  */
  function mymodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['webform_submission']->fieldable = TRUE;
  $entity_types['webform_submission']->set('field_ui_base_route', 'entity.webform.edit_form');
  }

2. With Comment module enabled, go to administer comment types: admin/structure/comment and add a comment type that targets webform submissions.
3. Go to webform administration page: admin/structure/webform and click on the Operations dropdown for the webform you wish to add comments to. You should now find a Manage Fields link.
4. Click on Manage Fields and add a comment field of the type you just created.

Answer (score 0):

As @NewZeal mentioned I create custom module with this code:

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
    $entity_types['webform_submission']->fieldable = TRUE; 
    $entity_types['webform_submission']->set('field_ui_base_route', 'entity.webform.edit_form');
}
```

Now you can create fields for each webform but I if you go to `/admin/structure/webform/manage/MYFORM/form-display` i got this error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\webform\Breadcrumb\WebformBreadcrumbBuilder->build() (line 159 of modules/webform/src/Breadcrumb/WebformBreadcrumbBuilder.php).
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136574)